# pandas sum boolean values by rows, can contain NaN

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe like this, and I want to find how many students have more than **two** school experiences.

| Name | Primary school | Middle school | High School |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | Tampli school | Compton School | The Tampli high school |
| Peng | New york public | North Star School |  |
| Hu | L.A public | South planick school |  |

```
df["Name","Primary school","Middle school","High School"].isnull()
```

| Name | Primary school | Middle school | High School |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | False | False | False |
| Peng | False | False | True |
| Hu | False | False | True |

We can use df.count_value() to get the column summary, but how could I get sum value of rows?

desired output

```
df["Enough Experience?"]= #code
```

| Name | Primary school | Middle school | High School | Enough experience? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | False | False | False | True |
| Peng | False | False | True | False |
| Hu | False | False | True | False |

Comment: I am confused - description is about counts, table test if at least one value has True...

Comment: @jezrael The first table is the output of first part of code. Generally, count how many falses in isnull of three schools (because it gives whether value is exist or not) . If more than 2, return True, otherwise return False

Comment: Do not use `isnull`, directly `sum`. The `True` are equivalent to `1` when using `sum`

Comment: sure, `isnull` is necesary. If need count `NaN`s

Comment: @XJTLUmedia - is accepted correct answer? Because `The first table is the output of first part of code`

Comment: @jezrael There are possible NaN in dataframe, and we can't drop it. so I use Isnull first to check if the value exist or not. More simply, if there are more than 2 value filled in, then it should return True in enough experience

Comment: @XJTLUmedia even with NaN you should not need `isnull` (unless you want to count `False` values). Maybe provide an example with NaNs.

Comment: **You don't need to use `.isnull()`**. You can directly sum boolean values, yes even containing NaNs. [By default, pandas does`sum(... ,skipna=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

Comment: Also, set 'Name' to be your index. Then you can simply do `df.sum(axis=1)`. That's why indices are helpful.

Comment: @smci I updated my question, I think it is more clear now

Comment: @smci FutureWarning: I got a error output with this problem.  "Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'numeric_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.
  f1[schoollist].sum(axis=1,skipna=True)"

Comment: @smci maybe I can skipping that column when selecting?

Comment: XJTLU: yeah you could, that's the harder more clunky way. But since you essentially have a dataframe of booleans/ints with a string 'Name' as index, it's way simpler to treat it that way. Indexes are your friend, learn to like them and use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
   Name  Primary school  Middle school  High School
0  Alex             1.0            NaN          NaN
1  Peng             1.0            NaN          2.0
2    Hu             2.0            7.0          0.0
3  John             NaN            NaN          NaN


# test if all non missing values 
cols = ["Primary school","Middle school","High School"]
df["Enough Experience?1"] = ~df[cols].isnull().any(axis=1)
# test at least 1 missing values 
df["Enough Experience?2"] = df[cols].isnull().any(axis=1)

# test at least 2 missing values per rows with `sum`
df["Enough Experience?3"] = df[cols].isnull().sum(axis=1).lt(2)
df["Enough Experience?4"] = df[cols].count(axis=1).ge(2)
print (df)
   Name  Primary school  Middle school  High School  Enough Experience?1  \
0  Alex             1.0            NaN          NaN                False   
1  Peng             1.0            NaN          2.0                False   
2    Hu             2.0            7.0          0.0                 True   
3  John             NaN            NaN          NaN                False   

   Enough Experience?2  Enough Experience?3  Enough Experience?4  
0                 True                False                False  
1                 True                 True                 True  
2                False                 True                 True  
3                 True                False                False
```

Solutions by table ouput - testing if all values are not missing:

```
# test at least 1 missing values 
cols = ["Primary school","Middle school","High School"]
df["Enough Experience?1"] = df[cols].notna().all(axis=1)
df["Enough Experience?2"] = ~df[cols].isna().any(axis=1)
df["Enough Experience?3"] = df[cols].isnull().sum(axis=1)<1
print (df)
   Name  Primary school  Middle school  High School  Enough Experience?1  \
0  Alex             1.0            NaN          NaN                False   
1  Peng             1.0            NaN          2.0                False   
2    Hu             2.0            7.0          0.0                 True   
3  John             NaN            NaN          NaN                False   

   Enough Experience?2  Enough Experience?3  
0                False                False  
1                False                False  
2                 True                 True  
3                False                False
```

Comment: f1[schoollist].isnull().sum(axis=1)<1 actually make the expected output

Answer (score 2):

Based on your **description** of the problem, I think you need:

```
df['Enough experience?'] = df.drop(columns='Name').sum(axis=1).ge(2)
```

You shouldn't use `isnull`, that checks for NaN/None, instead `sum` the booleans (each `True` counts for `1`).

output:

```
   Name  Primary school  Middle school  High School  Enough experience?
0  Alex           False          False        False               False
1  Peng           False          False         True               False
2    Hu           False          False         True               False
```

To get the total:

```
experienced_students = df.drop(columns='Name').sum(axis=1).ge(2).sum()
```

output: `2`

Count of schools:

```
df['number schools'] = df.drop(columns='Name').sum(axis=1)

   Name  Primary school  Middle school  High School  number schools
0  Alex           False          False        False               0
1  Peng           False          False         True               1
2    Hu           False          False         True               1
```